# How to Configure Jasper Server with Oracle 12c Database

Tags: java, xml, oracle12c, jasperserver

I'm working on configuring JasperReports Server 7.1 Community Edition. I want to configure the server using the Oracle 12c database rather than PostgreSQL. But it seems that I can only do so using enterprise edition. I don't need the features from Enterprise Edition, I just need to configure the server using Oracle 12c.

I found out that there are some configuration files missing in '/buildomatic/conf_source/db/'
and the files can be added manually to accomplish this task but I have no idea on how to do that. I found out that I have to modify the files given for MySQL or PostgreSQL and make some tweaks to use those for Oracle. I need to know which files to work with and what are the changes to be made for Oracle 12c?

Comment: Hello @brainEatingZombie. Have you resolved this issue?